# Enable SSL in Mongo 3.0.5

Tags: mongodb

I have been able to start mongo in ssl mode with the following command:
mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile ~/datastore.pem --sslCAFile ~/datastore.ca-bundle

datastore.pem was created by combining .crt (issued by comodo ssl) and .key (used during generating csr)

I am trying to connect to my mongo instance with the below command:
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile ~/datastore.pem --sslCAFile ~/datastore.ca-bundle

I get the following message when I try to connect:
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.5 
connecting to: test 
2015-08-10T03:35:43.456+0000 E NETWORK  SSL peer certificate validation failed:certificate not trusted 
2015-08-10T03:35:43.458+0000 E QUERY    Error: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for 
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14) 
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179 
I am very new to SSL setup in mongo, any pointers to successfully connect to mongo using SSL would be helpful, I have read the security section of 10gen multiple times but no direct answer.